# URL var with wildcard

Tags: javascript, url, wildcard

I have this JS code in my HTML

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="formurl" id="form1" method="post" action="../search.php" onSubmit="document.getElementByName('url').value=;">
<input type="hidden" id="url" name="url" value="" />
<input type="hidden" id="usrgn" name="usrgn" value="" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var searchprimary = "https://site12.org/";
  var searchsecundary1 = "https://site12.org/folder2/";
  var searchsecundary2 = "https://www.site12.org/folder2/folder3/";
  var searchsecundary3 = "https://www.site12.org/folder2/folder3/folder1/";
  var searchsecundary4 = "https://www.othersite.org";
  var searchsecundary5 = "https://www.othersite.org/folder4/folder3/";
  var searchsecundary6 = "https://www.othersite.org/folder4/folder10/";


</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = window.location.hostname;
    var y = document.referrer;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = y;
    var z = document.referrer.split('/')[2];
    if (z == searchprimary){}
    else if (z == searchsecundary1) {}
    else if (z == searchsecundary2) {}
    else if (z == searchsecundary3) {}
    else if (z == searchsecundary4) {}
    else if (z == searchsecundary5) {}
    else if (z == searchsecundary6) {}
    else
    {
        var usrgnt = navigator.userAgent;
        document.forms["formurl"].url.value = y;
        document.forms["formurl"].usrgn.value = usrgnt;
        document.forms["formurl"].submit();
}
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to create a wildcard like this

https://site12.org/folder2/* 
( /folder2/, folder3/folder4/, folder5/, etc)

I did this but it's not working for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var searchprimary = "https://site12.org/folder2/[^ ]*";
    var searchsecundary4 = "https://www.othersite.org.com/folder4/[^ ]*"; 
   </script>
```

Does anyone have any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: What are you expecting the wildcard to do?

Comment: Don't use multiple enumerated variables! Use an appropriate data structure, such as an object or an array.

Comment: You don't really need a wildcard if all you want to do is see if z contains a given string.

Comment: So than you would use match/test with the reg exp. Or just use indexOf/includes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Regular Expressions. I think you wanted to use that but didn't know how (based on your questions).

Here's how:

```
var yourURL = "....";
var urlRegEx = /http:\/\/site.com\/page\/[^/\s]+\/?/i;
if (urlRegEx.test(urlRegEx)) { /* ... */ }
```